# How to retrieve a value from a variable outside of a condition?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JS, but I don't know if it's possible to do what I want to achieve.

I have a variable named `btcVariationTotal` which is in a condition, and I want to retrieve the value of this variable in another variable called `tmp`, but this variable is not included in the condition.

My problem is that `tmp` always shows me 0. I don't understand why? And how can I solve this problem, please?

[image]

I really want to retrieve the value outside the condition.

```js
console.clear();

let wsBtc = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade');

let btcStockPriceElement1 = document.getElementById('btcValue1');
let btcStockPriceElement2 = document.getElementById('btcValue2');


let btcLastPrice = null;
let btcStockObject = null;

wsBtc.onmessage = (event) => {
  btcStockObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
};

let btc1 = 0, btc2 = 0;
let btcVariation_1_2 = 0;
let btcVariationTotal = 0; 

let tmp = 0; 



let btcRunTimers = setInterval(() => {
  let minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
 if (minutes === 51) {
    let val1 = parseFloat(btcStockObject.p).toFixed(1);
    let price = parseFloat(btcStockObject.p).toFixed(1);

    btcStockPriceElement1.innerText = price;
    btcStockPriceElement1.style.color =
      !btcLastPrice || btcLastPrice === price
        ? 'black'
        : price > btcLastPrice
        ? '#AAFF00'
        : 'red';

    btcLastPrice = price;
    btcStockObject = null;

    btc1 = val1;

  }

if (minutes === 52) {
    let val2 = parseFloat(btcStockObject.p).toFixed(1);
    let price = parseFloat(btcStockObject.p).toFixed(1);

    btcStockPriceElement2.innerText = price;
    btcStockPriceElement2.style.color =
      !btcLastPrice || btcLastPrice === price
        ? 'black'
        : price > btcLastPrice
        ? '#AAFF00'
        : 'red';

    btcLastPrice = price;
    btcStockObject = null;

    btc2 = val2;

    btcVariation_1_2 = ( (parseFloat(btc2) - parseFloat(btc1)) / btc1 * 100);

    document.getElementById("btcResult1").innerHTML = btcVariation_1_2.toFixed(2);
    
  }

  btcVariationTotal = (parseFloat(btcVariation_1_2));
  console.log("btc variation => " + btcVariationTotal);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = btcVariationTotal.toFixed(2);
  tmp = btcVariationTotal;


}, 60000);


console.log("tmp => " +  tmp);
```

Comment: Your `tmp` is set inside of the `setInterval()` callback, which runs every 60 seconds forever. When do you expect the `console.log()` to be executed? As you might have discovered; `setInterval()` only schedules to run code in the future. It doesn't block the rest of the code from continuing, so `console.log("tmp => " +  tmp)` is called immediately after scheduling, before the first time the interval callback function is invoked.

Comment: Yes, but I store the value here => `tmp = btcVariationTotal;`

Comment: Yes, but like I said, that is part of the `setInterval()` callback, so it it set _after_ the `console.log()` runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is that you are in fact doing what you want: you are retrieving
the value of the `btcVariationTotal` variable, and storing in `tmp`, which is
defined in the outer scope, outside of your `setInterval` callback.

The only problem you have is that you can't display a modified `tmp`, and
that's because you only call `console.log` **before** setting `tmp`, you never
call it **after** it has been changed. User **Ivar** has tried to explain that in
the comments, maybe I can detail it a bit more:

At time t=0, you set `tmp = 0`, you set your timers with `setInterval`, associating
a callback function (which does NOT run at this point), and then you call
`console.log` to display tmp (it's 0, because no callback has ever run).

At time t=60s, your callback runs, sets `btcVariationTotal` to some value, and
assigns that to `tmp`. No attempt is made to display the `tmp` value. Then this
gets repeated every 60s.

So what's missing is for you to write some code that displays the `tmp` value
**after** it has been changed. One way to do that, is to put that code inside
some other callback and arrange for it to be called. I suggest a simple
button. Add the following somewhere in your html page:

```
<button id="show-tmp">Show tmp</button>
```

Add the following lines at the end of your JS code:

```
let btn = document.getElementById('show-tmp');
btn.onclick = function() {
    console.log(`tmp: ${tmp}`); 
}
```

Now clicking on the button will show you the value inside `tmp`; if you do it
before the first 60 seconds, it will show 0; if you do it afterwards, it will
show whatever value was in `btcVariationTotal`.